# How to remove (auto) formatting of text when posting a question

Tags: support, markdown

I asked a [question in arcade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265419/have-a-dwarf-build-a-wall-one-z-level-lower-than-he-is) where I tried to paste some ACSII art into the question. The question auto-formatted the ASCII art and I couldn't figure out how to remove that formatting. I ended up taking a picture of the ASCII art and posting the picture instead.

My question is: how do I remove all formatting from text before I post it?

My ASCII art:

[image]

---

My ASCII art after stack exchange auto-formatted it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap it in code formatting:

```
######
#....#
#...^#
#....#
######
```

Just add 4 spaces before every line, and it will turn into code. The benefit is that code uses a mono-typed font, so it is very suitable for ASCII art.

Comment: Nice.  I completely forgot about the non-proportional font that stack exchange uses, so your answer covers not only my questions but also a problem that I hadn't even considered. Up-voting but will wait a while on accepting to allow other replies.

Answer (score 2):

You could either put it in a code block (although it isn't actually code) or alternatively wrap it with <pre> tags as I've done below.

```
######
#....#
#...^#
#....#
######
```